# How to solve a linear program with some infeasible constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint-programming

I want to solve the following LP:
\begin{array}{ll}
\underset{x}{\min} &Ax+b\\
&s.t \quad C_ix\leq0 \quad \text{for} \quad i=1...N 
\end{array}

I know that not all of the constraints could be feasible. So is it a good idea if I rewrite it like this with slack variables $\alpha_i$?
\begin{array}{ll}
\underset{x,\alpha}{\min} &Ax+b+\lambda\sum{\alpha_i}\\
&s.t \quad C_ix\leq \alpha_i \quad  \quad,\alpha_i \geq 0 \quad ,\quad \text{for} \quad i=1...N 
\end{array}

But then i need to also tune $\lambda$. Is there any better way to solve the above LP without needing to use a hyperparameter like $\lambda$?

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by the rather mysterious formulation "solve an infeasible problem". I.e. what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to interpret this as a multi-objective problem: $$\begin{align} \min\>&Ax+b\\ \min\>&\sum \alpha_i\end{align}$$ There are different ways to solve this depending on how we need to deal with the trade-offs.